# Change WooCommerece Single Product page Layout

Tags: php, woocommerce

I am looking help to change Woocommerce single product page layout. Currently *Description*, *Reviews*, *Additional Information*, and *Questions and Answers* are buttons next to each other. I want to edit them to be viewed one below each other in the following format.

1. Description
2. Additional Information
3. Reviews
4. Question and Answers.

Please refer to this link to know the current layout assigned.

https://phoneghanti.com/product/samsung-galaxy-j8/

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

In order to change the layout of the Woocommerce single product page.

Here, Single Product Page hooks, all you need to do in your functions.php is “add_action(‘place-hook-here’,’your-PHP-function-here’);” and you can place your custom functions in active theme.

**Note:
The child theme is the best way for theme/plugin customizations.**

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-single-product-page/

https://businessbloomer.com/?s=single+page